# Opening a file in an application that is already running in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, mutex, application-singleton

I know there is a question with the following title:
"[Opening a file in an application that is already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793224/opening-a-file-in-an-application-that-is-already-running)"

This gives the answer to the question targeting WPF applications. I am working on a WinForms application where doubleclicking a specific file should start the program and open the file. Of course this is simple. Now when the application is already running I would like to open a file in the running application when it is doubleclicked.

To do this the application needs to be a singleton. I prefer the Mutex approach as described in this great article of ["Sanity Free Coding"](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html)

Now I would like to know how to open a doubleclicked file into the running singleton WinForms applications. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84270/WPF-Single-Instance-Application) does what you want. Also, you should get the file opened as a parameter for your singleton instance. I have not tested it though, use another implementation but I don't need more parameters from the second instance.